# How do I append int in a int array(java)?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, append

I am working on an one of coding practice from codingbat which is

[array coding practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAUIl.png)

**First one works with no problem,**

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {
  int max = Math.max(nums[0], nums[2]);
  int[] result = {max, max, max};
  return result;
}
```

**however, second one have compile problems and I cannot figure out why. Please have a look at my code. Thanks!**

```
public int[] maxEnd3(int[] nums) {  
   int first = nums[0];
   int last = nums[2];
   int[] result = new int[2];
   if (first >= last) {
      result = {first, first, first};
   } else {
      result = {last, last, last};
   }
   return result;
}
```

Compile problems:
missing '}' or illegal start of expression

Comment: So what is difference between the code that compiles and the code that doesn't compile? Also, you have an if/else statement that will always return a value, so how will the `return nums` ever be executed? Also, how do you know the nums array will contain 3 values? You should have an edit to check the size of the array so you don't get an index out of bounds. Don't assume your data is correct.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my second code. When you check the link, the length of the array is set to 3. The difference between the first code and the second code is from the first code, I create an array and append values in one line. However, in the second code I create an array and append values in two different lines.(int[] result = new int[2];result = {first, first, first}; or result = {last, last, last};)

Comment: In the first case the declaration of the array is done in a single statement. In the second case you try to do it in two statements and the type information isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] result = {max, max, max};
```

The above compile because the compile knows the type.

```
return {first, first, first};
```

The above doesn't compile because the compiler doesn't know the type.

It should be:

```
return new int[] {first, first, first};
```

Or, if you want to assign it to a variable you still need to use:

```
result = new[int] {first, first, first};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. And I finally fixed the compile problems. But why do we need to specify the type to return array. I was wondering because when I return boolean, String, or int, I can just do return true; return "A", return 0;

Comment: I'm not a compiler expert, but the compiler isn't smart enough to know what the type should be. Normally {} are used for blocks of code, so I guess it doesn't recognize that you actually want to create an array. It assumes the statements in your block of code is incorrect. Primitives are different than objects. You don't need to create an instance of a primitive. "A" is a String literal. The compiler will create a String object for you since Strings are so commonly used.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time with detailed explanation. You are the best ^^b